# Is it possible to set capacity for C# string intern pool?

Tags: c#, string, string-interning

Normally, when init a collection such as dictionary, if we know how many key-value pairs ahead, we could use

```
var dict = new Dictionary<>(capacity);
```

Is it possible to set capacity for C# string intern pool? (I think internally it is like a dict.)

**Edits**:

I am profiling a unity game.

And there are about 20 MB strings. The number of these strings are about 400000.

After intern these strings, the memory is about  7MB and the number is about 98000 strings. So I guess I could reduce memory use intern.

The reason I use intern instead of dictionary-like data structures, because the architecture issues. There is no easy way to inject such data structures.

And the strings are all config data which means they will be persistent once starts.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @mjwills I assume it use resize. I don't want unnessary resize. Since the number of elements are really big.

Comment: You are probably doing something wrong if you are interning that many strings

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/storage-of-string-literals?view=msvc-160]

Comment: What make you think string interning is the basis for your performance issue?

Comment: @JohnWu That link isn't about C#. And that info certainly isn't accurate for C#.

Comment: @mjwills If he's asking, and telling us he has a lot of strings, he's probably doing *something* wrong, so my intuition tells me. *EDIT* Quote: "Since the number of elements are really big"

Comment: @Charlieface I'd be interested in what he means by "really big". And how they are being interned. And how he determined (guessed?) that is a problem.

Comment: As I know, dictionary capasity is not about  constatnt length, but about memory allocation, you can add items later in dictionary and it's capasity will grow.

Comment: The pool is managed by the CLR, and as such you have no control over its implementation. You will essentially be able to intern strings until you run out of swap file, any issue you have is likely nothing to do with how the CLR handles the LOB that holds the pool, and likely everything else you are doing which at this stage sounds more than a little suspicious

Comment: @mjwills  I am profiling a unity game. And there are about 20 MB strings. After intern these strings, the memory is about  7MB. So I guess I could reduce memory use intern. What will be the problem using intern? The number of these strings are about 400000. After intern there are about 98000 strings.

Comment: @Charlieface As far as I know, most resize double the inital collection. Lets say 10. After  10 times, it will be 10240. If I am pretty sure it will be 5121. Then I can just set the capacity as 5200 more or less.

Comment: `I am profiling a unity game. And there are about 20 MB strings. After intern these strings, the memory is about 7MB.` I am surprised that 20MB fits into 7MB.

Comment: `After intern there are about 98000 strings.` I cannot understand what you mean by this. Where did the other 302,000 go?

Comment: As a general rule, I would say this - I have never (in my entire development career) called `string.Intern`. I would be surprised if it is useful for 99.9% of developers outside of Microsoft.

Comment: @mjwills Suppose two string instance 'a' (address X) and 'a'(address Y), when intern there are only one instance in pool.Both two string point to the same instance. The two string instance a come from deserialization process which I cannot easily  manage them use some data structures as I mentioned in edits.

Comment: I would need to see a code sample. But the short answer is that it is very rarely useful. I'd need to see code to understand whether it is useful in your case.

Comment: Note that it wouldn't be difficult to create a private intern pool. A `static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>` would be a perfect private intern pool.

Comment: The only problem of string interning is that the lifetime of the "intern dictionary" is equal to the lifetime of the program. There is no way to reduce it (and it isn't self-reducing). But in your particular case, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @xanatos Personally, given this is a load-once scenario I would use a `HashSet<string>` and just lock or spin-wait on insert

Comment: @xanatos `The only problem of string interning is that the lifetime of the "intern dictionary" is equal to the lifetime of the program. ` Although the microsoft doc said so. But it is not true in Unity impls. But yes. In my particular case, I don't really care about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to restrict the size of the intern pool.